# How to import a third party library delivered via CDN into Angular/Typescript with Angular-CLI without using declare var?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, office-js

I'm using the Angular-CLI (Angular 4, Typescript, Webpack) to create an Excel Add-in with Office-js.  The Add-In is working fine, but due to Microsoft's move to require getting Office-js via a CDN I am having trouble figuring out how to import Excel into the app.

The Excel object is being loaded into the global namespace, and I am able to access it with `declare var Excel: any`.  Sadly, this method blows away my autocomplete.  Other third party libraries allow things like `import * as _ from 'lodash'`, but I don't know how to follow this pattern when the file is delivered via a CDN using a script tag in index.html.

I have npm installed @types/office-js, and when I remove `declare var Excel: any;` My editor's autocomplete beings to work as expected.  Unfortunately, at this point the typescript compiler fails to compile.  If I explicitly include `/// <reference types="office-js"/>` at the top of the file, things work as expected, but I feel like this is a clunky solution.

How can I import Excel using syntax like `import { Excel } from '@microsoft/office-js'` or `import * as Excel from 'office-js'`?

Comment: It seems there's no other solution?

Comment: Hi @Jolleyboy. I have faced the same issue. Did you solve it? I have played with `@microsoft/office-js` yesterday and finally has switched to the CDN. It worked great I believe because of the caching or so. Today I have faced the same issues: `Cannot find name 'Office'` in case of typings + CDN. And loosing of intellisence with `declare var Excel: any;`. So what the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it's the same problem that I had with iziToast (that doesn't have native support to Angular), but I hope it helps you. So,

instead of importing the lib like 'import * as iziToast from 'iziToast', I did this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

let iziToast = require('assets/js/iziToast.min.js')

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  sucess(message?: string) {
    iziToast.success(......)
  }
}
```

Then works like a charm

Comment: Could you indicate how exactly its done for a cdn delivered script ?